In MS Access I am using a TabControl. I would like the selected Tab of be green and the unselected Tabs to be gray. How can I do this?
How can I change tab colors.
The selected tab should be green.
The non selected tabs should be grey.
Can this be done?  How?
I tried several suggested items from the internet and looked at the property settings and have not accomplished anything.

Did you try Pressed Color property? Setting this property will affect the entire tab page. The "tab" cannot be colored separately. Option is to emulate a tab control with buttons, subform container(s), and VBA.

This worked fine.  It only changed the font color but that is OK.  Thanks

Then you must have set Pressed Fore Color property, not Pressed Color.
